# Динамическое расположение элементов в зависимости от ширины строки

Tags: java, android, android-customview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть лист типа `String` и мне нужно, в зависимости от ширины строки, динамически размещать 2, 3 или 4 элемента в одну строку. Как это возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что верно понял, но, похоже, вам помогут вот эти библиотеки:

1. [android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)
2. [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

А вот тут с некоторыми объяснениями: [тык](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/11/17/3396/)

Comment: Да да да, благодарочка! то что нужно)